# When plotting my own pd.dataframe in seaborn, and trying to reposition the axis--the axis disappears

Tags: seaborn, axis

my problem is that I want to plot my data, and want the axes X and Y to intersect at (0,0). But when I do `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))`, the X axis disappears.

The following code snippets is to recreate the error:
Here is how I am creating my dataframe with my data:

```
#### Create Pandas DF
col_names =  ['algorithm', 'seed', 'iteration', 'performance']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)

df['algorithm'] = [f'Algorithm {i}' for i in range(num_algos)
                                    for _ in range(num_seeds)
                                    for _ in range(num_iterations)]
df['seed'] = [i for i in range(num_seeds)
                for _ in range(num_iterations)] * num_algos

iters = num_algos * num_seeds
df['iteration'] = np.linspace(0, 1000, num_iterations).tolist() * iters

df['performance'] = np.random.rand(iters * num_iterations)
```

If I normally plot, with no change of spine position:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data = df,
                  x ='iteration',
                  y = 'performance',
                  hue = 'algorithm',
                  style = 'algorithm'
                  )
plt.show()
```

I get the following

[image]

However, since I want to reposition the axis, I try the following code:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data = df,
                  x ='iteration',
                  y = 'performance',
                  hue = 'algorithm',
                  style = 'algorithm'
                  )
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
plt.show()
```

I get the following graph with no x axis at all
[image]

What is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The axis appears to be outside the plot.  You could try something like `plt.tight_layout()` or `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)` to create extra space.

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to change the axis *limits* rather than the spine position?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Instead of

```
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
```

Do `ax.set_xlim(0,1000)`